# Confusing Output from npm outdated Command

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, npm-install

Can someone please explain the meaning of the following output:

```
$ npm --version
3.10.8
$ npm -g outdated npm
Package  Current  Wanted  Latest  Location
npm       3.10.8   4.0.2  3.10.9
```

According to the [docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/outdated), it says the "Wanted" column should display the currently installed version:

> If there's no available semver range (i.e. you're running npm outdated --global, or the package isn't included in package.json), then wanted shows the currently-installed version.

Also see:

```
$ls -l $(which npm)
/usr/local/bin/npm -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js
```

So in addition to the discrepancy between the "Wanted" value and the docs, I'm also wondering why the "Latest" column doesn't seem to show the latest version since 4.0.2 seems to be the latest.

Answer (score 0):

Your npm version should be outdated so try to execute this in the console to get the last version.

```
npm install npm@latest -g
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the response, however, this should be a comment not an answer.

Comment: Check the update, after that it should display correctly